# start_query_execution targeting incorrect database

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

I'm trying to call Athena from lambda. However, the call fails because it is trying to use the wrong database.

I am setting QueryExecutionContext : `'Database':'ap_ath_meta2_use_tch'`

But the query history states  : `ap-gdb-callcenter-use-tch" database`

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask This query ran against the
> **"ap-gdb-callcenter-use-tch" database**, unless qualified by the query.

Have been through the documentation and still can't work it out.
If anyone can point out my error - much appreciated !
Thanks

```py
def athena_partition():
    print('[] > athena')
    bucket_name = 'mybucket'
    client = boto3.client('athena','myregion')
    config = {
        'OutputLocation': 's3://' + bucket_name + '/'
       # 'EncryptionConfiguration': {'EncryptionOption': 'SSE_S3'}
    }
    # Query Execution Parameters
    sql = 'MSCK REPAIR TABLE ap_ath_meta2_use_tch.getresources'
    context = {'Database':'ap_ath_meta2_use_tch'}
    print(sql)
    client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=sql,
        QueryExecutionContext=context,
        ResultConfiguration=config
    )

    print('[] < athena')
```

Comment: Does `ap_ath_meta2_use_tch` exists in `myregion`? My guess, is that you use a wrong region in which you don't have `ap_ath_meta2_use_tch` database, instead you have only `ap-gdb-callcenter-use-tch`.

Comment: Thanks, but yes it exists. I've also modified the code to explicit state 'us-east-1' - where the DB resides.

Comment: Would this exact query work in Athena console? I have a feeling that you get this error because you have underscores in you database name which considered to be special characters. Could you try to surround it with either quotes orback ticks (always forget which one), e.g. `MSCK REPAIR TABLE "ap_ath_meta2_use_tch"."getresources"`